# How to call a countdown timer from 5 second and it should decrement to 1 second in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an application in which I want that when I run my application initially it should show a screen for 2 seconds that displays warning about the app and just after 2 seconds a countdown should start from 5 seconds that should decrement from 5 second to 1 second.

Comment: @Rani to show warning for 2 seconds then make a image and then set aas default image. And for countdown make view and show for 5 second by using [self perform selector] with nstimer.

Comment: This is far too broad, and seems to be abandoned anyway. I recommend putting it on hold (can also be closed as unclear).

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways:

1. `[NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval: .....]`
2. `[self performSelector: withObject: afterDelay:]`

Answer (score 1):

so if i got your point you want to display a warning screen and after 2 seconds you want to show the user count down start from 5 and end at 1 .. well this can done easy by using a timer and counter as following :

- define a `NSTimer` and start it once the warning view is shown .. your definition will be like this:

  ```
  timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerFires) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

  [timer fire];
  ```
- define a global integer and set its initial Value to 7 (lets suppose you name it *counter*).

-in timerFires selector you decreament counter by 1 and check its value when its equal to 5 start to show its vlaue on UILabel for example and when its 1 invalidate the timer and do you what you want at this point .. the timerFires will be like this:

```
- (void)timerFires
{

   counter --;
   if(counter ==5)
   {
      //show its Value
   }

   if(counter ==1)
   {
      [timer invalidate];
      timer = nil;

      //Do other stuff
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60 target:self selector:@selector(updateFunction) userInfo:NULL repeats:YES];
```

In updateFunction you can write your code for count down.
You can also set "repeats:NO" and to call the updateFunction at the end of itself if it is necessary